# FieldSet is not working

Tags: apex, fieldsets

I am trying to learn FieldSet from this [Salesforce document](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_dynamic_vf_field_sets.htm) but i am getting the following Error while saving this class

```
public class MerchandiseDetails {

public Merchandise__c merch { get; set; }

public MerchandiseDetails() {
    this.merch = getMerchandise();
}

public List<Schema.FieldSetMember> getFields() {
    return SObjectType.Merchandise__c.FieldSets.Dimensions.getFields();
}

private Merchandise__c getMerchandise() {
    String query = 'SELECT ';
    for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : this.getFields()) {
        query += f.getFieldPath() + ', ';
    }
    query += 'Id, Name FROM Merchandise__c LIMIT 1';
    return Database.query(query);
}}
```

> Error: MerchandiseDetails Compile Error: dimensions is not a fieldSet of Merchandise__c at line 10 column 16

should i need do extra settings to enable FieldSet?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://ap1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/fields_editing_field_sets.htm

For your Merchandise_*c Object you will need to configure your fieldset.The above example in salesforce guide assumes you already have a fieldset named Dimensions for your Merchandise*_c Object.

refre the above link on how to create fieldsets in salesforce for an object and make sure you refer same name as you assign in fieldset in your apex code .

Comment: yes, i solved it, i haven't add the 'Dimension' fieldset on Merchandise_c Object, but i cant gauge The fields in the "Available for the Field Set" option and actual use of FieldSet.

Comment: The actual usage is say you have used fieldset in your code and you have a visualforce page .Now say in future your business demands one more field on visualforce .You may not go to your code for this .Just drag the field in fieldset and code dynamically picks it up!

Comment: Thanks Monith kumar for make me understand!!,and Available for Field set says : "If a field is marked as Available for the Field Set, it exists in the field set, but the developer hasn't presented it on the packaged Visualforce page. Administrators can display the field after the field set is deployed by moving it from the Available column to the In the Field Set column." What it means?

Comment: There are two columns.1)Available column -This displays all the fields available for fieldset 2)Fieldset column which an admin adds a field from availabel columns  .Say you mark field while creating package as available for fieldset then later an admin can add that in fieldset column if that has to be presented on visualforce page .

Answer (score 1):

You have not added `dimensions` field set on your `Merchandise__c` object. Create `dimensions` field set and your problem will be resolved.

And second thing in your `getMerchandise()` method you have hard coded `Id` and `name` fields, it should not be there. If someone comes and add `ID` or `name` field explicitly in your field set in that case in your query there would be 2 `ID` or `name` fields and your code will fail.

so the code should be like this -

```
private Merchandise__c getMerchandise() {
    String query = 'SELECT ';
    integer i = 0;
    for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : this.getFields()) {
         if (i == 0) {
            query += f.getFieldPath();  
          }
          else {
            query +=  ', ' + f.getFieldPath(); 
          }
            i++;
     }       
    query += ' FROM Merchandise__c LIMIT 1';
    return Database.query(query);
}
```

Comment: thanks pramod for your point towards query, but this just i am learning..